# Is this A good Example to apply the command design pattern?

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{           
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(textBox1.Text,true);                                    
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        textBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
    else
        textBox1.Text  = "The clipboad does not contain any text";
}
```

I write this application using C# Windows Form Application

Comment: What do you picture as being the command object?

Comment: 1. If it work this should probably just be posted on codereview. 2. How do you plan to change it from what it currently does? 3. What about it do you think would be better after changing it? 4. You don't really need the command pattern in C#; you can just use delegates.  An `Action` or `Func` can be considered a "command", but I don't see how it helps you here.

Comment: what is the Correct way of write this using command design pattern?

Comment: If you don't see how to easily and naturally implement a pattern in a given situation, chances are the pattern isn't a good fit for the job anyway.  Don't worry so much about solving a problem *using pattern X*, and just solve the problem.  If a certain pattern is good for the job, in one way or another it will reveal itself anyway.

Comment: Note to close voters and down-voters.  IMO, this is not a bad or non-constructive question.  It is a >>mis-guided<< question, in the sense that the OP has an incorrect notion of the purpose of design patterns.  However, since the initial Answer does a good job of correcting that, the Question as a whole serves a useful purpose, and should be allowed to stand.  (IMO ...)

Answer (score 3):

Let's talk for a second about patterns and cults.

You hear a lot about "learn design patterns" and "you suck if you don't use design patterns" and "you should use the X pattern" and all that.  There's a whole patterns movement going on...a cult, even...encouraging people to patternify *everything*.  Saying that this is how people ought to do things.  That there's a pattern for everything, and by $DEITY, you should be using it.

Guess what?  About 80% of it is crap.  They're vastly overemphasizing the role and scope of design patterns.

Patterns are *a tool*.  Nothing more.  They are not their own reason to exist.  They are not the key to world peace.  They are not the solution to all problems, and you should not use them just because they are there, or because you drank the cultists' Kool-Aid.  You should use them only when and because *they are meant for the job you need to do*, and they thus make sense.

**Design patterns' entire purpose -- their *only* purpose -- is to reduce overall complexity.***  Wherever they do not do that, they are not a good fit, and you should *ignore them*.

So every time you're thinking about using some particular pattern, ask yourself the one most important question:  **How will it simplify things?**

<sup>* Note, i said *overall* complexity.  Applying a design pattern often involves adding complexity to one part of the app in order to remove much more of it from some other part.  As long as there's a net loss of complexity, the pattern's still worth looking at.</sup>

---

Now, as for your code.

You've asked about changing that little snippet around to use the Command pattern.  I suppose it's possible; i see "copy" and "paste" actions, which could conceivably be parameterized with a reference to the text box.

Question is, though: **How will it simplify things?**

Without any context other than that snippet, i don't see how you'd gain from adding CopyCommand and PasteCommand classes, and code to instantiate and use them in precisely one place.  Perhaps when you're doing lots of copying and pasting in other places, it might be worth it...but right now, no.  It feels like you're trying to shoehorn a pattern in where it doesn't want to go.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the Correct way of write this using command design pattern?

First, read and understand what cHao wrote in his Answer.  (He is not saying that design patterns are crap.  He is saying that the way a lot of people *use* and *talk about using* design patterns is crap.  I agree ...)

Your question doesn't have a good answer:

First, you need to ask yourself why you are trying to use any design pattern at all here.  If you are just doing it because you've been told that using design patterns is a good thing, you are doing it for the wrong reason.

Second, repeat that question replacing "any design pattern at all" with "the Command design pattern" ...  What are you trying to achieve here by applying this particular design pattern?  If you can't answer that, then you need to 1) go back and review the Command design pattern, and *understand* what it achieves, and 2) then decide whether you actually need what it achieves in your program.

If I was to directly answer your initial and follow-up questions, I would have to say:

- the example code snippet doesn't appear to use the Command design pattern,
- without seeing the rest of your code, I cannot say whether it *should* be using that design pattern at all, and
- without seeing the rest of your code, I cannot say *how* it should use that design pattern.

---